# Apache Tomcat 405 error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to run on the ecclipse IDE am getting the Apache 405 error...
Below is my servlet code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class MyFirstServlet extends HttpServlet  {
    public void Service(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.write("<html>");
        out.write("<title>Welcome</title>");
        out.write("<body bgcolor=blue>");
        out.write("<h1>Hi Wassup</h1><br>");
        out.write("<h2>Great that you are studying Java</h2>");
        out.write("</body>");
        out.write("</html>");
        out.close();


    }

}
```

and below is my web.xml file.

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>firstservlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>MyFirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>firstservlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/homepage</url-pattern>]
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Somebody please help me to resolve this issue..as i am trying for first time.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented your response HTML in the constructor of the servlet. What you actually need to do is implement the doGet/doPost methods and put your code into them.

Like

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.write("<html>");
    out.write("<title>Welcome</title>");
    out.write("<body bgcolor=blue>");
    out.write("<h1>Hi Wassup</h1><br>");
    out.write("<h2>Great that you are studying Java</h2>");
    out.write("</body>");
    out.write("</html>");
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this:

```
public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
     Service(request, response);
}
```